# Check if Variable exists and === true

Tags: php, if-statement, notice

I want to check if:

- a field in the array isset
- the field === true

Is it possible to check this with one `if` statement?

Checking if `===` would do the trick but a PHP notice is thrown. Do I really have to check if the field is set and then if it is true?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### If you want it in a single **statement**:

```
if (isset($var) && ($var === true)) { ... }
```

---

#### If you want it in a single **condition**:

Well, you could ignore the notice (aka remove it from display using the [`error_reporting()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function).

Or you could suppress it with the evil [`@`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) character:

```
if (@$var === true) { ... }
```

> This solution is **NOT RECOMMENDED**

Comment: I thought that the notice is an error but if it is ok to just supress it I am fine :) thanks a lot

Comment: @distractedBySquirrels don't forget to accept the question if you find it correct.

Comment: @Trurh: sorry :) Was here with my phone.

Comment: `@` operator is bad most of the times. I wouldn't suggest anyone to use it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick ...

```
if( !empty( $arr['field'] ) && $arr['field'] === true ){ 
    do_something(); 
}
```

Comment: I think the point is kinda have it in a single condition... But maybe that's what he meant and I misunderstood.

Comment: He said one IF statement, that is one. Having && doesn't make it two, does it? If so, then I guess I was wrong. Didn't come to what you replied tho', clever :)

Comment: My problem was that the notice was thrown when I checked in a single statement. But the @ will Do the trick I think.  I thought I was doing something wrong :-/

Comment: empty() and inset() respectively will take that error away, well at least it does for me. However @ is shorter and sweeter indeed. Best of luck for you future ventures :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative, just for fun

```
echo isItSetAndTrue('foo', array('foo' => true))."<br />\n";
echo isItSetAndTrue('foo', array('foo' => 'hello'))."<br />\n";
echo isItSetAndTrue('foo', array('bar' => true))."<br />\n";

function isItSetAndTrue($field = '', $a = array()) {
    return isset($a[$field]) ? $a[$field] === true ? 'it is set and has a true value':'it is set but not true':'does not exist';
}
```

results:

```
it is set and has a true value
it is set but not true
does not exist
```

Alternative Syntax as well:

```
$field = 'foo';
$array = array(
    'foo' => true,
    'bar' => true,
    'hello' => 'world',
);

if(isItSetAndTrue($field, $array)) {
    echo "Array index: ".$field." is set and has a true value <br />\n";
} 

function isItSetAndTrue($field = '', $a = array()) {
    return isset($a[$field]) ? $a[$field] === true ? true:false:false;
}
```

Results:

```
Array index: foo is set and has a true value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `!empty`:

```
if (!empty($arr['field'])) {
   ...
}
```

This is precisely equivalent to your conditions by DeMorgan's law. From [PHP's documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty), `empty` is true iff a variable is not set or equivalent to `FALSE`:

```
  isset(x) && x
  !(!isset(x) || !x)
  !empty(x)
```

As you can see, all three of these statements are logically equivalent.