# Check in PHP if a specific query is in URL

Tags: php, url, if-statement, parameters

I am trying to check if a URL has a specific query within a URL with multiple parameters:

```
$parts = parse_url('http://my url?queryA=valueA&queryB=valueB&queryC=valueC ....');
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
```

I have used the below to get the value of the query;

```
$query['queryA']//outputs valueA
```

However, I want to check if "queryA" is indeed within the URL queries:

```
echo $parts['query'] // Outputs the full query - queryA=valueA&queryB=valueB&queryC=valueC

// Trying for
if($parts['query'] == 'queryA') {
    // queryA is in the URL
}
```

Comment: google: "PHP check variable exists" ... [Result #1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) - Example #1 part II shows you how to check this for arrays.

Comment: @ash That *possible* duplicate you say (or think) it is; that other question is about checking if something `isset()` and not about parsing a url. Hardly a duplicate in my view, just because the accepted answer contains `array_key_exists()` isn't related between both questions. *Two different animals here*. Plus, that other question doesn't even mention `parse_url()`. Best to dig a bit deeper if you're going to mark a question as a duplicate. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is not use the use of `isset` over `array_key_exists`, the OP is trying to determine if a variable exists before using it - therefore, this question shows little effort from the OP to search google and find the answer themselves.  The duplicate does show how to test if a variable exists - it may not be 100% the same words but it certainly is 100% the same solution.

Comment: @ash Well, nobody else thought it was a duplicate (so far anyway), as it wasn't upvoted. If someone does (eventually) upvote it and more than once, sure... why not. Just *"my 2 cents"* on it though. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- sure, and we could be splitting at hairs. I personally think the reputation rewards for this level of laziness is unacceptable; but then again it's not my call, just my opinion on the matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908163/check-if-variable-exists-and-true

Comment: @ash - I overflowed the question type with no real solution, so asked it in my own words for a simple solution..inwhich I got from #Saty in a timely manner.

Comment: Sure, you're every right to. I'm merely objecting to the question (hence my duplicate link) and refusal to up vote (I'm every right to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)** to check `queryA` key present in `$query` array

```
$parts = parse_url('http://my url?queryA=valueA&queryB=valueB&queryC=valueC');
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
if (array_key_exists('queryA', $query)) {
    echo "queryA element is in the array";
}
```

Comment: Great answer, not going to up-vote since this question should be closed.