# If Variable doesn't exist echo

Tags: php, var

I want to write some thing if for example $var doesn't exist this what i want

```
$var = "Powered by company name";
if(!$var){
echo "doesn't exist ";
}
```

I want to use it in copyright 
if my copyright doesn't exist in the page i want to show the msg "doesn't exist "

Comment: Did you check `isset()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if Variable exists and === true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908163/check-if-variable-exists-and-true)

Comment: You are trying to make sure some copyright notice is in the script? You do know that this is not robust at all? If someone removes the copyright from the script, then why shouldn't the check also get removed?

Comment: Can you give us a more practical example of what you want to achieve? What you provided is really vague.

Comment: Your silence is not doing anyone a favour

Answer (score 0):

you can not do that insted you do
define $var firstlike demo

```
$var="";
```

now code

```
if($var==""){
}else{
}
```

Comment: This will raise an exception if variable is not defined.

Comment: yes that why i say for define $var="";on page start

Comment: But he is not sure if the variable is defined, if he is defining, then he does not need to check for it's existence.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset($var) && ($var === true)) { ... }
```